# Sub::Override doesn't override DBI methods. Why?

Tags: perl, overriding

I'm writing a fork of [DBI::Log](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI::Log), my purpose is to make it conditionally-pluggable to be able to log SQL queries more flexible, e.g. only from particular module or after specified call.

I faced with strange problem - `Sub::Override` can not override `DBI::db::*` and `DBI::st::execute` methods.

Scheme of overriding is following

1) I save reference to original method to variable, e.g. `my $orig_execute = \&DBI::st::execute;`

2) Create a new function with adding some additional logging code, e.g.

```
sub _execute {
    my ( $sth, @args ) = @_;
    warn "Execute is working!";
    my $log = dbilog( "execute", $sth->{Database}, $sth->{Statement}, \@args );
    my $retval = $orig_execute->( $sth, @args );
    dbilog2($log);
    return $retval;
}
```

3) Replace old to new function using `Sub::Override`

```
my $sub = Sub::Override->new;
$sub->replace( 'DBI::st::execute', \&_execute );
```

[Here is a full code of changed DBI::Log module](https://github.com/pavelsr/dbilog/blob/plugged/lib/DBI/Log/Plugged.pm). It must do same as [original DBI::Log](https://github.com/zorgnax/dbilog/blob/master/lib/DBI/Log.pm), just use Sub::Override, so original unit tests must pass.

If I run [test.pl](https://github.com/pavelsr/dbilog/blob/plugged/test.pl) and [added debug output](https://github.com/pavelsr/dbilog/blob/plugged/lib/DBI/Log/Plugged.pm#L40) script I see that `Sub::Override` is working, but for some reason overrided function can not start - no `Execute is working!` [message](https://github.com/pavelsr/dbilog/blob/plugged/lib/DBI/Log/Plugged.pm#L44).

Comment: Is your test.pl script the only new test thing you have? What about the t/ directory?

Comment: If you want to do logging, [DBI has various callback methods that you can use](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Callbacks). Overwriting existing methods is far more hacky than just using the API the module provides.

Comment: @simbabque, no, actually in t/ directory of repository there are also some new tests regarding issue https://github.com/zorgnax/dbilog/issues/2, but they don't affect on problem.

Comment: DBI is a very complex module, I would not recommend ever trying to do anything beyond the documented interfaces (which are very extensive). For example every DBI object consists of an 'inner' object and an 'outer' object and there is a weird tied interface.

Comment: Untested, but perhaps [`Class::Method::Modifiers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers)'s `around` would be worth a try instead.